# (JScript) Complex Tree Logic with more than one root

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree, logic

I'm facing a deadend on building the logic of my complex tree-like structure where it has more than 1 source/root and many interconnected intersections. To make it easy to explain, I include the mini version of the actual content with the logic as intended.

There are several main things to look at here:

1. button #1 and #7 is the starting point, where there are no pre-requisite for activating them
2. when there is a button de-activated, the rest with no source linked will be de-activated
3. the logic becomes complex when the situation get complex

Below here are the example of complex situations

symbols:

 = active

O = inactive

======================

O==================

====================

======O=========O

=================O====

lets say I de-activate #6, it will become like this:

======================

O==================

===========O=========

======O=========O

=================O====

What I can do is telling #10 to check wether #6 or #9 is active, if it's not then set #10 inactive. another situation is like below:

======================

O==================

====O================

============O===O

=================O====

and then I turn off #6

======================

O==================

====O=======O=========

============O===O

=================O====

This situation is far more complex than the 1st one, #2 has 3 sources to check, which are #1, #5, and #3. #1 and #5 are false, however #3 is true, thus, it becomes complex because doesn't know where to check from or multiple checking, it needs to check #3, #4, #6, to make sure there is a source of "power" coming from that side.

This sample is only around 1% of my whole project, any shorter logic are welcome.

Please try on the snippets first to grasp the concept.

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
var actives = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
  actives.push(false);
};

drawLine(document.getElementById('b1'),document.getElementById('b4'));
drawLine(document.getElementById('b2'),document.getElementById('b8'));
drawLine(document.getElementById('b7'),document.getElementById('b12'));
drawLine(document.getElementById('b4'),document.getElementById('b10'));
drawLine(document.getElementById('b11'),document.getElementById('b13'));

function toogle(event){
  actives[(event.target.innerHTML)] = !actives[(event.target.innerHTML)];
  logic();
  visual();
}

function visual(){
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for (var i = 1; i < buttons.length + 1; i++){
    if (actives[i]) {
      buttons[(i-1)].style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
    } else {
      buttons[(i-1)].style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
  }
}

function logic(){
    if (actives[8] == false && actives[10] == false) {
  actives[9] = false;
}
if (actives[2] == false && actives[10] == false) {
  actives[3] = false;
  actives[4] = false;
  actives[6] = false;
}
if (actives[2] == false && actives[7] == false) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    if (i != 1) {
      actives[i] = false;
    }
  }
}
//[][]
if (actives[2] == false && actives[8] == false) {
  /* not working, not sure why?
  for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    if (i != 7 || i != 1) {
      actives[i] = false;
    }
  }
  */
  actives[3] = false;
  actives[4] = false;
  actives[5] = false;
  actives[6] = false;
  actives[9] = false;
  actives[10] = false;
  actives[11] = false;
  actives[12] = false;
  actives[13] = false;
}
if (actives[9] == false && actives[4] == false) {
  actives[6] = false;
}
if (actives[4] == false && actives[10] == false) {
  actives[6] = false;
}
if (actives[3] == false && actives[10] == false) {
  actives[4] = false;
  actives[6] = false;
}
if (actives[2] == false && actives[8] == false) {
  actives[5] = false;
}
if (actives[9] == false && actives[6] == false) {
  actives[10] = false;
}
if (actives[7] == false && actives[5] == false && actives[9] == false) {
  actives[8] = false;
}
if (actives[3] == false && actives[6] == false) {
  actives[4] = false;
}
if (actives[2] == false && actives[4] == false) {
  actives[3] = false;
}
if (actives[10] == false) {
  actives[11] = false;
  actives[13] = false;
  actives[12] = false;
}
if (actives[1] == false && actives[5] == false && actives[6] == false) {
  actives[2] = false;
  actives[3] = false;
  actives[4] = false;
}
if (actives[1] == false && actives[5] == false && actives[10] == false) {
  actives[2] = false;
  actives[3] = false;
  actives[4] = false;
  actives[6] = false;
}
if (actives[1] == false && actives[8] == false) {
  actives[2] = false;
  actives[3] = false;
  actives[4] = false;
  actives[5] = false;
  actives[6] = false;
  actives[9] = false;
  actives[10] = false;
  actives[11] = false;
  actives[12] = false;
  actives[13] = false;
}
if (actives[1] == false && actives[7] == false) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    actives[i] = false;
  }
}
}

function drawLine(a,b){
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(a.offsetLeft+25,a.offsetTop+25);
      ctx.lineTo(b.offsetLeft+25,b.offsetTop+25);
      ctx.lineWidth = 1.5;
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
      ctx.stroke();
  }
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }

  button {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="viewport" 
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<html>
<body>
<canvas id='mycanvas' width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<button id="b1" onclick="toogle(event)" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; top: 20px; left: 20px;">1</button>
<button id="b2" onclick="toogle(event)" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; top: 20px; left: 90px;">2</button>
<button id="b3" onclick="toogle(event)" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; top: 20px; left: 160px;">3</button>
<button id="b4" onclick="toogle(event)" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; top: 20px; left: 230px;">4</button>
<button id="b5" onclick="toogle(event)" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; top: 90px; left: 90px;">5</button>
<button id="b6" onclick="toogle(event)" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; top: 90px; left: 230px;">6</button>
<button id="b7" onclick="toogle(event)" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; top: 160px; left: 20px;">7</button>
<button id="b8" onclick="toogle(event)" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; top: 160px; left: 90px;">8</button>
<button id="b9" onclick="toogle(event)" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; top: 160px; left: 160px;">9</button>
<button id="b10" onclick="toogle(event)" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; top: 160px; left: 230px;">10</button>
<button id="b11" onclick="toogle(event)" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; top: 160px; left: 300px;">11</button>
<button id="b12" onclick="toogle(event)" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; top: 160px; left: 370px;">12</button>
<button id="b13" onclick="toogle(event)" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; top: 230px; left: 300px;">13</button>
</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, it doesn't look like a tree, it's a graph as you have a cycle 2-3-4-6-10-9-8-5-2. So any tree algorithms would likely to fail. As I understood, you just need to check if there is no path back to node 1 or 7 from any node and there is no node disabled on the way, right?

Comment: yes, the tree only describe something that coming from 1 source/root, what I have is like a snake tree, which can in and out on one or more ways

Comment: and so, if the logic is correct, it will work like the #10, which will clear all the tree below this parent upon disabling, and also preventing the child from activating if the #10 is not activated, so it work both ways. it's hard to do when I have multiple sources.

Comment: You'll need 3 states instead of 2: active, user-deactivated, non-sourced. Nodes with the last status would become active again when user re-activates a node that they had de-activated earlier on. Or am I misunderstanding the challenge?

Comment: as for 2-3-4-6-10-9-8-5, lets add 7, okay so now the water source coming from #7. so it's 7-8-9-10-6-4-3-2-5, if I disabled #5, only #5 is disabled, then disable #3, #2 also got disabled because there is no source from #1 or #5, and if I disable #8, all of them will get disabled except #7. that's the logic I want to make.

Comment: think it like a water valve, the nodes = water valve. disabled = closed, active = open, so you can see clearly how the water move, that's the logic I wanted.

Comment: So you need a third status for "unreachable"?

Comment: if the logic is correct, then "unreachable" should be automatically applied. try on #11, #12, #13 before activating #10, it will stay inactive when you press it.

Comment: the different about water valve is, upon activating the valve, it does not close automatically if there's no water source nearby. in this node map, if the source is null, then it will get disabled upon activating. lets call it a "safety procedure for a water current"

Comment: Yes, I understand the automatic part. I just don't see in your code an attempt to distinguish between closed and unreachable.

Comment: I see that your code is mostly a sketch without any "real" functional part. Think about it this way: 1) You need to generate a graph of nodes (valves) so that you can easily traverse it. Right now there is no way you can easily build your graph like that. 2) You need a traversal algorithm like Depth First Search to be able to check every node/valve of your graph. And you need to configure it properly. Only after that you can think of any other logic you want to put in. If you want I can write an answer but only in form of some recommendations and basic concepts.

Comment: Well, okay, I will try to make it as close as the actual of my intention, sorry but need to wait a bit...

Comment: for those who still wondering about the state of activation, gray button = false(inactive), while pink button = true(active), the picture has blue button(which I don't know why it's there and it's not what I wanted. remember, the root of the diagrams are #1 and #7, so you can start activating from any or both of those root, not others.

Comment: as you can see from the updated snipped, logic section, I have around 2150 characters for the logic codes for this 13 nodes (which maybe still has missing logic), can you imagine how many characters I need to create logic for 600 nodes? yes, a lot. that's why I'm stuck with that heavy logic, I'm looking for a shorter logic here in this forum.

Comment: I reverted the edits I made to your question, and I will move on, as despite my comments for clarification in this thread, and despite I thought I had clarification, I apparently didn't get what you want and still don't. Good luck.